# mysql - How to select row count group by column if null display 0

Tags: mysql

I have a table like below and I want to count rows group by each date and status (true or false only), display 0 if no record

```
date            name    status
2019-10-01      A       true
2019-10-01      B       false
2019-10-01      C       true
2019-10-02      A       true
2019-10-02      B       true
```

How can i display like below? Thanks.

```
date        count   status
2019-10-01  2       true
2019-10-01  1       false
2019-10-02  2       true
2019-10-02  0       false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `CROSS JOIN` the distinct values of `date` and `status` to each other to get a table of all combinations of each, and then `LEFT JOIN` that to the table to get the `COUNT` values:

```
SELECT d.date, s.status, COUNT(y.name) AS count
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT date
      FROM yourtable) d
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT status
            FROM yourtable) s
LEFT JOIN yourtable y ON y.date = d.date AND y.status = s.status
GROUP BY d.date, s.status
```

Output:

```
date        status  count
2019-10-01  false   1
2019-10-01  true    2
2019-10-02  false   0
2019-10-02  true    2
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/umXfToHEVeBDRmmDsAzEET/0)

If you might have values of `status` that you want to ignore (perhaps `null`), change that derived table to a `UNION` of the values you want to check e.g.

```
SELECT 'true' AS status
UNION ALL
SELECT 'false'
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/umXfToHEVeBDRmmDsAzEET/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
    Select count(*) as count from table group by 
date,status ;
```

Comment: hi, but i want to display 0 if no record.

Comment: Well count always returns integer value instead of null . So just try this and let me know